# PKIX error after installing Eclipse CDT 2021-06 and trying marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-marketplace, pkix

I've just installed Eclipse CDT 2021-06 after having previously used 2021-03. When I try to browse the Eclipse marketplace, I get this error:

```
MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=linux&platform.version=4.20: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can I fix this problem, or work around it somehow?

Note: I'm using SLES 15 (The Enterprise version of SUSE :-( ).